# Why are iron and copper used more than other materials to make cooking pots?

Tags: thermodynamics, material-science, metals

Why are iron and copper used more than other materials to make cooking pots?

Answer (score 4):

They are relatively inexpensive, easily formed into useful shapes, nontoxic, and they conduct heat well. Please note that aluminum belongs on this list too, and that certain combinations of metals work even better (copper-cladding on the bottom of a stainless steel pan, for example).

Answer (score 1):

Copper is quite a malleable metal, it doesn't require a high temperature to form it. Also, copper is a relatively noble metal, which means it is fairly resistant to corrosion, which means only trace amounts will end up dissolving into the food.

When you do ingest copper it will not accumulate in the body, the liver is equipped to get rid of it. (There are diseases where the some component of the copper removal mechanism is not there, due to damage of a gene coding for that part of the mechanism. To someone with such a disease copper is toxic, as it will accumulate in the body.)

Preparing (or worse: storing) highly acidic food in a copper vessel does create danger of copper toxicity, as acids do cause significant corrosion.

Source of the toxicity information:  Wikipedia article about [copper toxicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper_toxicity)